# Parsing data from pdftotext .txt file output using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdftotext

I am trying to implement a parsing function that will grab data from parts of a .txt file created using pdftotext. I hate PDFs! Essentially, I use pdftotext on a PDF file using the -raw option and I get a file like this:

```
SPORTS FANZ Order #62659
June 24, 2023
SHIP TO
Abe Lincoln
123 Main St
New York, NY 12345
United States
BILL TO
Abe Lincoln
123 Main St
New York, NY 12345
United States
ITEMS QUANTITY
Virginia Tech Hokies Basketball Cassell Coliseum Panoramic
Picture
Virginia Tech Hokies Panoramic Picture Select
VAT5M
1 of 1
Thank you for shopping with us!
Sports Fanz
123 Liberty St, Chester NY 12345, United States
```

Example with phone number and quantity of 2:

```
SPORTS FANZ Order #12345
June 24, 2023
SHIP TO
Abe Lincoln
123 Main St
New York, NY 12345
United States
(123) 123-4567
BILL TO
Abe Lincoln
123 Main St
New York, NY 12345
United States
ITEMS QUANTITY
Virginia Tech Hokies Basketball Cassell Coliseum Panoramic
Picture
Virginia Tech Hokies Panoramic Picture Select
VAT5M
2 of 2
Thank you for shopping with us!
Sports Fanz
123 Liberty St, Chester NY 12345, United States
```

Example with phone number (different format) and two SKUs:

```
SPORTS FANZ Order #58083
January 6, 2023
SHIP TO
Abe Lincoln
123 Main St
New York, NY 12345
United States
+12345678900
BILL TO
Abe Lincoln
123 Main St
New York, NY 12345
United States
ITEMS QUANTITY
Nebraska Cornhuskers Women's Volleyball Devaney Center Panoramic Picture
Nebraska Cornhuskers Panoramic Picture Select Frame
UNE11M
1 of 1
Kansas City Chiefs Super Bowl 54 Champions Panoramic Picture
Kansas City Chiefs SB 54 Champions Panoramic Picture Unframed
NFLSBC20CHF
1 of 1
Thank you for shopping with us!
Sports Fanz
123 Liberty St, Chester NY 12345, United States
```

I've implemented the following code already to grab some of the data:

**Function for grabbing text between two strings**

```
Public Function SuperMid(ByVal strMain As String, str1 As String, str2 As String, Optional reverse As Boolean) As String
'DESCRIPTION: Extract the portion of a string between the two substrings defined in str1 and str2.
'DEVELOPER: Ryan Wells (wellsr.com)
'HOW TO USE: - Pass the argument your main string and the 2 strings you want to find in the main string.
' - This function will extract the values between the end of your first string and the beginning
' of your next string.
' - If the optional boolean "reverse" is true, an InStrRev search will occur to find the last
' instance of the substrings in your main string.
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, temp As Variant
On Error GoTo errhandler:
If reverse = True Then
    i = InStrRev(strMain, str1)
    j = InStrRev(strMain, str2)
    If Abs(j - i) < Len(str1) Then j = InStrRev(strMain, str2, i)
    If i = j Then 'try to search 2nd half of string for unique match
        j = InStrRev(strMain, str2, i - 1)
    End If
Else
    i = InStr(1, strMain, str1)
    j = InStr(1, strMain, str2)
    If Abs(j - i) < Len(str1) Then j = InStr(i + Len(str1), strMain, str2)
    If i = j Then 'try to search 2nd half of string for unique match
        j = InStr(i + 1, strMain, str2)
    End If
End If
If i = 0 And j = 0 Then GoTo errhandler:
If j = 0 Then j = Len(strMain) + Len(str2) 'just to make it arbitrarily large
If i = 0 Then i = Len(strMain) + Len(str1) 'just to make it arbitrarily large
If i > j And j <> 0 Then 'swap order
    temp = j
    j = i
    i = temp
    temp = str2
    str2 = str1
    str1 = temp
End If
i = i + Len(str1)
SuperMid = Mid(strMain, i, j - i)
Exit Function
errhandler:
MsgBox "Error extracting strings. Check your input" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Aborting", , "Strings not found"
End
End Function
```

**Extraction Sub**

```
Sub extractPDF()
    
    Dim phoneNumber, shippingInfo, shippingAddress, itemInfo, poNumber As String
    Dim iTxtFile As Integer
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strFileText As String
    strFile = "C:\blah\blah\blah\#62875.txt"
    iTxtFile = FreeFile
    Open strFile For Input As FreeFile
    strFileText = Input(LOF(iTxtFile), iTxtFile)
    Close iTxtFile
    
    Dim regexPattern As String
    Dim regex As Object
    Dim matches As Object
    Dim match As Object
    
    ' Regular expression pattern
    regexPattern = "Order #\d{5}"
    
    ' Create a regular expression object
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    
    ' Set the pattern and ignore case
    With regex
        .Pattern = regexPattern
        .IgnoreCase = True
    End With
    
    ' Perform the search
    Set matches = regex.Execute(strFileText)
    
    ' Loop through the matches
    For Each match In matches
        ' Print the matched value
        poNumber = Right(match, 5)
    Next match
    
    shippingInfo = SuperMid(strFileText, "SHIP TO", "BILL TO")
    shippingAddress = SuperMid(shippingInfo, "", "United States")
    phoneNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(SuperMid(shippingInfo, "United States", "BILL TO"))
    itemInfo = SuperMid(strFileText, "ITEMS QUANTITY", "Thank you for shopping with us!")
    Debug.Print "PO #: " & poNumber
    Debug.Print "Phone Number: " & phoneNumber
    Debug.Print shippingAddress
    Debug.Print itemInfo

End Sub
```

This gets me the shipping info, which I further break down into shipping address and phone number (if applicable), PO #, and the block of text containing the item information. What I'm struggling with is how to extract SKU and quantity data from the itemInfo block. Based on previous PDFs, the SKU line is always followed by the quantity line. So, in this example, SKU is VAR5M and quantity is 1 (if it was 2 it would say 2 of 2). Any ideas on the best way to implement what I need? Is there a better way to implement my needs than what I've already designed? Thanks for your help.

Comment: In order to optimum process a string, it is good to better describe the string itself pattern. If the pattern is not the same, at least, showing two examples. I mean: 1. Will it always have 21 lines? 2. Will always "Order" be on the first line? Will always "quantity line" be on the eighteenth line? Anyhow, will the data you need extracted be **in the line numbers where they are in the shown string**?

Comment: Please, edit your question and also show how the data to be returned **must** look: 62659 as Order. "123 Main St, New York, NY 12345, United States", on a single line (comma separated) or on four lines as in the text example etc. Will "Ship To" and "Bill To" always be extracted from four lines, for each?

Comment: Can you answer the clarification questions, please? You **must** describe the text to be processed, in order to receive an efficient answer. We are not mind readers... At least, is the order of characteristics to be returned the one you show? I mean, is "BILL TO" always following "SHIP TO"? And is "ITEMS QUANTITY" always following "BILL TO"? Where from the Phone information to be extracted and based on what **always** existing pattern?

Comment: @FaneDuru Thank you for your comments. I apologize for not providing more examples with variable output. I have edited my post and added different examples. As for your questions: Line output is variable, however, the structure of the PDF should always be the same based on my analysis of previously received PDFs. So the data might not be on the same line from file to file, but the order in which the data is structured should stay the same. A phone number is not always present, but always shows up after United States and before BILL TO. There can be multiple SKUs (as shown in example 3)

Comment: There can be one SKU with multiple quantities (example 2). The phone number format seems variable, but it's always in the same relative position. The SKU is always followed by the quantity in format "x of x". As for the variables themselves: I'm going to end up transferring them into an Excel worksheet, so printing them was solely for debug purposes. It'd be great to be able to parse address data into address, city, state, ZIP, etc. I think I've answered your questions, but please let me know if you have any more.

Comment: So, summing up in the following way, would it be a correct understanding? 1. No fixed positions of lines, but always the one keeping the order number will be the first. 2. "SHIP TO" will always be on the third line. 3. "SHIP TO" values can contain 4 or 5 lines (in case of phone number existence). 4. "BILL TO" will follow these 4 to 5 lines and its values will contain 4 lines, ending in "United States". 5. So named "SKU" will be followed by a string of a pattern "x of x", where x is the same number. They can be more than one. What does "SKU with multiple quantities (example 2)" mean?

Comment: Then, I would like you to parse/extract from your above examples "address, city, state, ZIP etc.". I am not familiar with American way of enumerating/showing them and I do not want doing only supposing...

Comment: 1. Yes, no fixed positions, but order number is in first line. 2. Based on all the PDFs I have seen, yes SHIP TO is on 3rd line. 3. SHIP TO values could conceivably contain up to 6 lines based on what I have seen. Name, Address 1, Address 2, City/State/ZIP, Country, Phone. That's why I'm been using that modified MID function, because I can grab everything between SHIP TO and BILL TO. 4. BILL TO is irrelevant to my needs, but  based on what I've seen it always matches SHIP TO minus the phone number. 5. Correct. There can be more than 1 SKU, or the quantity could be 2 of 2, 3 of 3, etc.

Comment: As for address information: Name, Address 1, Address 2 (if present), City, State, ZIP. Let me know if that answers your questions!

Comment: Is the state the abbreviated one (NY in your examples)? Then, **don't you need extracting anything from "BILL TO"**? So, does "multiple quantities (example 2)" means the fact that it is not 1 of 1? Do you consider 2 of 2 as multiple quantities? The single issue I do not have a solution for it (theoretically) looks the second address. Based on what to consider it an address? Starting with a number and ending with 'St' would be a good criteria?

Comment: Yes, NY is the state abbreviation. New York is the city, the number is the ZIP. BILL TO is always the same as SHIP TO, it just doesn't include a phone number if one is present.

Correct, multiple quantities are denoted by increased numbers after the SKU. 2 of 2 would mean a quantity of 2 for the SKU above it. 3 of 3 would mean 3, etc.

Address 2 is usually an apartment #, unit #, or suite, etc. It's additional identifying information when there are multiple dwellings at a single address. Sometimes people include those on the first address line, but sometimes they add a second line.

Comment: I cannot understand how to make the code 'understand' that it is a matter of a **second address**. Give me an example (examples, if more possibilities...). Does it start with a number instead of combination starting with City name? could this be a way? I clearly asked **Starting with a number and ending with 'St' would be a good criteria?** and you did not say anything to clarify the issue...

Comment: Unfortunately there is no "good" criteria to use, because the line could be many things. Let's leave out Address 2 for now. It's a rare case anyway.

Comment: We cannot leave it... If it exists, collecting the necessary data is done in a  different way. Can't you give some examples? I asked above: **Does it start with a number instead of combination starting with City name?** Isn't it a way of differentiation? Then, may "Bill To" data also contain a second address?

Comment: Some examples of what Address 2 line could be: Suite 3500, Apt #23, #23, 23, Unit #5, etc. Theoretically, they could put anything they wanted on the line.

Comment: Not containing **comma** in its string (against "New York, NY 12345") could it be a differentiation way?

Comment: That could work. I highly doubt there would ever be a comma in the Address 2 line if it exists.

Comment: OK, I will try preparing an answer. It will assume that you may have up two cases of SKU and their values. It can be adapted to deal with more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a text string stored in cell A1 and you would get SKU and Quantity with following code.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim objRegExp As Object
    Dim objMatches As Object
    Set objRegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With objRegExp
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "([A-Z0-9]+)\s*(\d+) of \d+"
        If .Test([a1]) Then
            Set objMatches = objRegExp.Execute([a1])
            For Each objMtch In objMatches
                With objMtch.submatches
                    If .Count = 2 Then
                        SKU = .Item(0)
                        QTY = .Item(1)
                        Debug.Print "SKU:" & SKU & vbNewLine _
                            & "Quantity:" & QTY
                    End If
                End With
            Next
        End If
    End With
    Set objMatches = Nothing
    Set objRegExp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Appreciate your response. Any way I could convert the quantity to just a number? So if it's 1 of 1, quantity should just become 1. 2 of 2 = 2, etc. Also, how could I store this data as a variable instead of printing it?

Comment: Also, this only seems to find the first SKU/quantity. If there are multiple (see example 3), it only returns the first one. Any way to alter the code to catch all of them?

Comment: I have updated the code. Hope it is what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Please, try the next function. It uses arrays and should be fast enough:

````
Function ExtractDat(arrTxt) As Variant
    Dim arrFin, mtch, arrH, arr, i As Long, k As Long
    '                                                           0                       1                        2                3             4       5       6          7             8                9                      10        11      12     13        14         15              16             17             18
    Const header As String = "Order number, (Ship To) Name, Address1, Address2, City, State, Zip, Country, Phone, (Bill To) Name, Address, City, State, Zip, Country, SKU1, Value SKU1, SKU2, Value SKU2"
    arrH = Split(header, ",")
    
    ReDim arrFin(UBound(arrH))
    
    With CreateObject("Vbscript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "\d{5}"
        .Global = False
        arrFin(0) = .Execute(arrTxt(0))(0) 'order number
    End With
    
    arrFin(1) = arrTxt(3)             'Send To Name
    arrFin(2) = arrTxt(4)             'Send To Address
    arrFin(3) = ""                    'No second Address (assumption...)
    
    mtch = Application.match("BILL TO", arrTxt, 0)
    If IsError(mtch) Then MsgBox """BILL TO" & " could not be found in the analyzed data...", vbInformation, "BILL TO missing": Exit Function
    If mtch = 8 Then 'no Phone number existing, no second Address, too...
        arr = Split(arrTxt(5), ", ") 'split City from State and Zip
        arrFin(4) = arr(0)            'Send To City
        arrFin(5) = Split(arr(1))(0)  'Send To State
        arrFin(6) = Split(arr(1))(1)  'Send To Zip
        arrFin(7) = arrTxt(6)         'Country
        arrFin(8) = ""                'No Phone number
    ElseIf mtch = 9 Then
        If InStr(arrTxt(5), ",") = 0 Then 'no comma in string (second address...)
            arrFin(3) = arrTxt(5)         'second Address
            arr = Split(arrTxt(6), ", ")  'split City from State and Zip
            arrFin(4) = arr(0)            'Send To City
            arrFin(5) = Split(arr(1))(0)  'Send To State
            arrFin(6) = Split(arr(1))(1)  'Send To Zip
            arrFin(7) = arrTxt(6)         'Country
            arrFin(8) = ""                'No Phone number
        Else    'No second address
            arr = Split(arrTxt(5), ", ")   'split City from State and Zip
            arrFin(4) = arr(0)            'Send To City
            arrFin(5) = Split(arr(1))(0)  'Send To State
            arrFin(6) = Split(arr(1))(1)  'Send To Zip
            arrFin(7) = arrTxt(6)         'Country
            arrFin(8) = arrTxt(7)         'Phone number
        End If
    ElseIf mtch = 10 Then 'second Address and Phone number exist
        arrFin(3) = arrTxt(5)         'second Address
        arr = Split(arrTxt(6), ", ")  'split City from State and Zip
        arrFin(4) = arr(0)            'Send To City
        arrFin(5) = Split(arr(0))(0)  'Send To State
        arrFin(6) = Split(arr(0))(1)  'Send To Zip
        arrFin(7) = arrTxt(7)         'Country
        arrFin(8) = arrTxt(8)         'Phone number
    End If
    arrFin(9) = arrTxt(mtch)        'Bill To Name
    arrFin(10) = arrTxt(mtch + 1)   'Bill To Address
    arr = Split(arrTxt(mtch + 2), ", ")
    arrFin(11) = arr(0)             'Bill To City
    arrFin(12) = Split(arr(1))(0)   'Bill To State
    arrFin(13) = Split(arr(1))(1)   'Bill To Zip
    arrFin(14) = arrTxt(mtch + 3)    'Bill To Country
    'extract SCUs and their values:
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrTxt)
        If arrTxt(i) Like "#* of #*" Then
            arrFin(15 + k) = arrTxt(i - 1)
            arrFin(16 + k) = Split(arrTxt(i))(0)
            k = k + 2
        End If
    Next i
    ExtractDat = Array(arrH, arrFin)
End Function
```
It can be used to return in the active sheet with such a code. It processes a text file, placing its content in an array and returns on the first two rows of the active sheet:
```
Sub UseExtractDat()
   Dim strFile As String, arrT, retArr
   
    strFile = "C:\blah\blah\blah\#62875.txt"
    'Place the content of the text file in an array (splitting by end of line)
    arrT = Split(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(strFile, 1).ReadAll, vbCrLf)

    retArr = ExtractDat(arrT)
    
    Range("A1").Resize(1, UBound(retArr(0)) + 1).Value2 = retArr(0)
    Range("A2").Resize(1, UBound(retArr(1)) + 1).Value2 = retArr(1)
End Sub
```
Please, send some feedback after testing it.
````

Comment: I will try this tomorrow when I get back to work. Thanks for your hard work. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: @Eli Greenberg Didn't you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it do what you need against what you required?

Comment: I'm going to be working on this project tomorrow. Work was incredibly busy yesterday and I'm only working a half day today. Tomorrow I will have free time to test this out. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I got a subscript out of range error for this line:     arrFin(12) = Split(arr(1))(0)   'Bill To State

Comment: Does it return such an error for **all the text you tried**? If you tested only one, please, test also others. The code is done to work on consistent data, based on logic we defined during the information change (in comments). Most probably, `arrTxt(mtch + 2)` is not the line having a comma after splitting by space (to extract the abbreviated State and Zip Code. If you move the cursor above the above  mentioned variable, **when stopped on error**, what does it show? Can you share the text file you try the code? I will immediately tell you where the problem is, or correct the code logic...

Comment: arrFin(12) = Empty is what the debug says. It looks like some of the PDFs do not have a comma between city and state. I may have to rethink how I do this. I appreciate your help though.

Comment: @Eli Greenberg You cannot solve such a problem in this way, I am afraid... Please, share the file in discussion to see what problem it **exactly** has and find a solution to work as you said until now, plus the new case. Maybe, the structure of the file is different, maybe something else you did not think about it. You can use a transfer site. [Here](https://easyupload.io/) is a free one, easy to be used. Please, put here the returned link.